# Jittery entity Interpolation when tick-rate exceeds framerate

Tags: javascript, networking, multiplayer

In my current game implementation, our game servers send data to the clients only 10 times per second (~every 100ms). However, due to recent changes, we are now expected to change the server tick-rate to 64 from the original 10.

Our interpolation algorithm has worked quite well up until now. However after we changed the servers to 64 tick, we are noticing a lot of jitter on the interpolated client entities.

I have reproduced the issue here:

```js
// CANVAS:
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
cxt.fillStyle = '#FF0000'
var radius = 10;

// START POSITION:
var ballSpeed = 0.1;
var x = 0;
var y = canvas.height / 2;

// NETWORKING
var posBuffer = [];
var tickrate = 64;

// RENDERING
var fps = 60;

// UPDATE LOOP CLIENT:
function update() {

  // INIT:
    var cTime = Date.now() - ((1000 / tickrate));
  while (posBuffer.length >= 2 && posBuffer[1].t <= cTime) {
    posBuffer.shift();
  }

  // INTERPOLATE:
  if (posBuffer.length >= 2 && posBuffer[0].t <= cTime && cTime <= posBuffer[1].t) {

      // INTERPOLATION AMOUNT:
      var interpM = (cTime - posBuffer[0].t)
          / (posBuffer[1].t - posBuffer[0].t);

      // SET POSITIONS:
      x = posBuffer[0].x + (posBuffer[1].x - posBuffer[0].x) * interpM;
      
    }
    
    // RENDER SERVER BALL:
    cxt.beginPath(); 
    cxt.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    cxt.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    cxt.fill();
    
}
window.setInterval(update, 1000 / fps);

// RECEIVE FAKE PACKET:
function packet(dat) {
    posBuffer.push({
      t: Date.now(), // CURRENT TIME
      x: dat.x
  });
}

// SIMULATE SERVER:
var serverX = 0; // X POSITION ON SERVER
var delta;
var lastUpd = Date.now();
function serverUpdate() {
        var tNow = Date.now();
        delta = tNow - lastUpd;
    lastUpd = tNow;
    
    // MOVE:
    serverX += ballSpeed * delta;
    
    // BOUNDS CHECK:
    if (serverX >= canvas.width) serverX = 0;
    
}
window.setInterval(serverUpdate, 1000 / tickrate);

// RANDOM FLOAT FUNC:
var randFloat = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

// SEND DATA TO CLIENT (FAKE):
window.setInterval(function() {
    packet({
        x: serverX
    });
}, (1000 / tickrate) * randFloat(0.9, 1.1)); // ADD SOME FAKE INCONSISTENCY
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

([You can also try it out in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ezd6orn/4/))

You can play with the tick-rate value at the top to see the changes in behaviour. I've also added some slight inconsistencies to the rate at which packets are received on the client to simulate a real network environment (lag, ping spikes etc).

Is there a different approach to this to account for higher tick-rates? Or is my original implementation simply wrong and we got lucky with the low tick-rates.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted please explain? Ive provided a runnable example that outlines the problem. Typical stackexchange

Comment: I'd recommend including your code snippet in the body of your question too. This makes it easier for users to scan when deciding how to vote on a question, and might let them spot the issue right away without clicking an external linke (whose code panes unfortunately do not render well on mobile). It also preserves your code for future readers so it's safe from link rot, so your question remains clear and complete even if the link stops working.